# BASH: How to make a script that update every X seconds and it repeats forever?

Tags: bash, loops, timer

lets say i have this line of codes

```
#!/bin/bash
xidel -se '//span[@class="last original"][1]' 'https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol=XAU='
exit 0
```

the output should be around 1,7K+

however, this script is only run once. I want it `loop forever every 5 or 10 secs` , what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like a loop, and `sleep`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just tried it, I thought `sleep` is like something else which might breaking the codes, I just tried the for,do,sleep,done sequences, and it just work. sorry for asking so simple question.

Comment: See `man watch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a loop and sleep

```
while :; do <your_command>; sleep <seconds>; done
```

Another option is to `watch` you command

```
watch -n <seconds> <your command> # use "<command>" if your command contains whitespaces
```

`watch` command has some quite nice features which comes out of the box

```
–errexit : freeze screen when the command failed
-beep: give a beep when the command failed
-differences: to highlight the differences in output.
```

Comment: `watch` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: i tried `watch`, but it does not compile the `\033[1m` code font fancy thing.
it prints out something like `^[1mBlablabla.....^(B^[m` it should be BOLD if it compiled normally.

Comment: so yeah, im sorry @Matthieu but i prefer the loop and sleep.

Comment: the `--color` option of watch does it I believe.

Comment: @SamDaniel okay, ill try and see about it tomorrow.

Comment: No problem, it's a matter of taste anyway ;)

Comment: @SamDaniel I tried the code today using `watch -cn 5 bash script.sh` and it execute perfectly. I tried to compare it with while loop method, it seems that the only minus on watch is that it re-execute the script from the very beginning, and if I have the `counting value (like timer, or other incremental)` inside the script, that will not work, since this script is more focusing more on the data gathering, then `watch` is perfectly fit.

Comment: @Matthieu dude, i pull back my word, it seems that `watch` is DEFINITELY the way to go on my script case. I can actually forcing it to work with `while loop` but, it gets complicated when `xidel` has not yet finishing fetching the data, it will `pause` the echo command and it left with `blank space` for a while until it loads up. putting clear command after the `xidel` also does not solving the matter, it will somehow has 1 stack of the old compiled data above the new one.

Comment: Sure, if you need to keep some context (environment) you'll have to go "manual" with a loop. Otherwise `watch` has many options to re-run your script.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( ; ; ))
do

clear #put clear if we don't want the script is executed under the old process
xidel -se '//span[@class="last original"][1]' 'https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol=XAU='

sleep 5 #Every 5 seconds

done
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.